# I'm coding an AI that understands english, in JavaScript... I have a small problem, when I ask it something in a string, it returns a array of NaNs

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

So what I did, is I coded a little function that turns letters to numbers, and I asked it what I coded it to do. I'm using Brain.js to make things easier. So when I ask it a string (turned into numbers with my working function) it returns a Float32Array, and the length is the correct response but instead of numbers like its supposed to, of which I will later on code a number decoder (numbers to string). It returned NaN again... Here's my code.

```
const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
var letters = []
for(var i=0; i < 26; i++){
letters[i] = String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
}
var AI = {
    ask: (txt)=>{
        return network.run(txt);
    },
    train: (inn, out) => {
        network.train([
            {input: inn, output: out}
        ])
    },
    num: (string)=>{
        let str = string.split('')
        let num = []
        for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++){
            num.push(letters.indexOf(str[i]))
        }
        return num;
    }
};
network.train([
    {input: AI.num('hello'), output:AI.num('hi')},
    {input: AI.num('hi'), output:AI.num('hello')}
])
```

note `AI.num()` turns a string to a array of numbers, and `AI.ask()` returns the response.

I get no errors, but I'm not sure what's going on, any other JS developers that can give me a hint?

explained this in the detailed desc

Comment: Tbh at this point I'm just gonna code my own AI, instead of using Brain.js

Comment: Documentation for the  [`train` method](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js#for-training-with-neuralnetwork) indicates entries in the number array should be in range 0 to 1.  I suspect violating the constraint could explain the  NaN values returned.